# Нужно в jQuery выбрать this вместе с другим селектором

Tags: jquery

Код например

```
$(".className, .className2")
```

работает правильно и *выбирает заданные классы* , но код

```
$("this, .className2")
```

*не возвращает* **текущий элемент** и **заданный класс**,

Как использовать ***this***  вместе с ***другим селектором***?

Comment: `$( $(this), ".className2")` вроде того

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/add/

```js
$(".button1").click(function(){
  $(this).add(".test").css("color", "red");
});
// или
$(".button2").click(function(){
  $(".test").add(this).css("color", "blue");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="test" value="some text" />
<button class="button1">Click 1</button>
<button class="button2">Click 2</button>
```